# Max voltage output of DS18B20

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, sensor, temperature, 1-wire

I am using the [DigiX](http://digistump.com/products/50) board and trying to connect a DS18B20 (one wire temperature sensor).

One of the issues with the DigiX is that it can only tolerate 3.3V on the I/O pins.

I have been trying to look through the [data sheet](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS18B20.pdf) to try and find out what the max output could be.
[image]
[image: Input logic high from data sheet]

Which, if I was powering with 3.3V would be too much? 3.3V +0.3V.

Is this the correct way to asses if there compatible and that I do in fact need a level shifter of some sort?

Thanks for your help, I just feel im missing something and it should be fine but I don't want to fry my board.

edit- I'm aware I could try measuring it with a multimeter but do not have access to one for a while and would not be confident in when or how t produce the max output current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking at "**Input** Logic-High", not the **output**. The datasheet does not list output logic levels but it is safe to assume that it will not output a level higher than Vdd. If you are powering it at 3.3V, you should be safe.